# Обработка массива данных MySQL в PHP

Tags: php, mysql

- Выбираю из таблицы значения товаров с помощью simple_html_dom.
- Нахожу страницу товара
- На этой странице ищу цену

Код работает, но неправильно: нет связки по id.
Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста.

```
include(PHPFOX_DIR_LIB . 'simplehtmldom' . PHPFOX_DS . 'simple_html_dom.php');
$aRows = Phpfox::getLib('database')->select('*')->from(Phpfox::getT('partner'))->execute('getSlaveRows');
//return $aRows;        
foreach ($aRows as $iKey => $aRow)
{
    $sId = $aRows[$iKey]['id'];     
    $sProduct = $aRows[$iKey]['product'];
    $aHtml = file_get_html('http://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q=' . $sProduct);
    $aDnsshop2 = $aHtml->find('a[class=ec-price-item-link]', 0);
    $aDnsshop3 = $aDnsshop2->href;
    $aDnsshop4 = 'http://www.dns-shop.ru' . $aDnsshop3;
    $aDnsshop5 = file_get_html($aDnsshop4);
    $aDnsshop6 = $aDnsshop5->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0);
    $aDnsshop7 = $aDnsshop6->content;

$sql = "UPDATE phpfox_partner SET dnsshoplink='$aDnsshop4', dnsshop='$aDnsshop7' WHERE id='$sId' ";
mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что выбрать-то надо? по-подробней вопрос, пожалуйста

Comment: Необходимо выбрать данные из таблицы обработать их и снова залить но в другие столбцы...

Comment: А почему у Вас `mysql_query($sql);` вне цикла?

Comment: а как нужно ????

Comment: Ну вообще-то получается, что Вы прокручиваетесь через массив, а `UPDATE` делаете ПОСЛЕ прокрутки. Т.е. фактически `UPDATE` применяется только для последней записи массива.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вставить `mysql_query()` внутрь цикла

```
foreach ($aRows as $iKey => $aRow)
{
    $sId = $aRows[$iKey]['id'];     
    $sProduct = $aRows[$iKey]['product'];
    $aHtml = file_get_html('http://www.dns-shop.ru/search/?q='. $sProduct);
    $aDnsshop2 = $aHtml->find('a[class=ec-price-item-link]', 0);
    $aDnsshop3 = $aDnsshop2->href;
    $aDnsshop4 = 'http://www.dns-shop.ru'. $aDnsshop3;
    $aDnsshop5 = file_get_html($aDnsshop4);
    $aDnsshop6 = $aDnsshop5->find('meta[itemprop=price]', 0);
    $aDnsshop7 = $aDnsshop6->content;
    $sql="UPDATE phpfox_partner SET dnsshoplink='$aDnsshop4', dnsshop='$aDnsshop7' WHERE id='$sId' ";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

Comment: изменил лишь    <code>$sql="UPDATE phpfox_partner SET dnsshoplink='$aDnsshop4', dnsshop='$aDnsshop7' WHERE id='$sId' ";
    Phpfox::getLib('database')->query($sql);</code>    но теперь другая проблема всё работает но не правильно идёт выборка не соответствует она индексу и всё